# Emscripten threads and custom web workers

Tags: three.js, web-worker, emscripten

I wrote an app to process gcode files in C/C++ compiled using emscripten. File parsing and processing is done in std::threads. Displaying in webgl is done using Threejs on main browser thread.

[image]

Now, I need to do offscreen canvas with threejs in a web worker so I can speedup display. The ideal situation is where I could access Wasm from main browser thread and web worker, so I could load the 3d webgl data to send to threejs from the web worker, and fetch statistical data from the main browser thread to display to the user.

[image]

If I do send the wasm memory and wasm module to the javascript manually created webworker, I get some stack-pointer exception when calling wasm functions (as it seems emscripten with pthreads initialize a thread stack for every workers). I mean here that a copied, pasted some parts of myapp.worker.js generated by emscripten into a worker file, let's say myapp.threejs.worker.js.

I have these options:

- Create a webworker form javascript, and access wasm only from this worker. Main browser thread must then communicate throught the worker to access wasm, affecting performance if some data is hardly transferable
- Create a new thread in wasm, create a C api to call javascript and threejs in worker. The problem is, if a spawn a thread from wasm, I can not actually send the offscreen canvas to the web worker through wasm, unless I can communicate directly from javascript to web worker spawned by wasm.
- Create a web worker from javascript, but communicate with wasm through main browser thread only. This approch suffers from UI blocking while receiving GL data, as it must pass on the UI thread.

My question is: is there a way to create a web worker from javascript and access wasm from web worker and main thread ? If not, is there a way to spawn a new web worker from wasm thread but post and receive message from javascript in main browser thread without passing through wasm ? Thanks.